# How to translate "No ads edition" to Russian?

Tags: перевод

Please tell me how to translate **No ads edition** to Russian. Thank you very much.

Comment: [версия без рекламы](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&q=%22%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%22+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0) — 24000 results

Answer (score 6):

Proper translation will be

> Версия без рекламы

[Google proof](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%22&oq=%22%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%22)

Comment: Thank you Nordik, i don't have enough reputation to vote you, maybe later.

Comment: *Avtokod*, well, I agree with you on pleasure of giving elaborate answers. But posting a short answers as an Answer isn't much more difficult than commenting: the Answer box is always straightforwardly open under the Question. Also there are some technical implications with answers in comments: from 0 Answers in question list to possible problems with indexing in search engines mentioned in the referenced MetaSE discussion. That's why you can see "Avoid answering questions in comments" note in empty Comment box.

Comment: It makes sense, I agree )

Comment: Removed from answer, as it's not part of such: I've just copied Avtokod's answer following the logic "Answers should be answers" (from [Answer or comment: what's the etiquette?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette)).   
**Let's agree on answering in answers even if they are simple and short.**

Comment: @AleksG , Here we will merely note that OP don't fit the rule [Can I request a translation?](http://russian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). And to be frank I was expecting that OQ will be closed. I don't bother the rest :) But my answer came pat, so ... I decide to drop a line in the Comment. That's all ))

Comment: @Avtokod No worries.  The comment above was part of the answer - and I just moved it to a comment.